# Setting a range as a selection, in order to resize a table

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to code a macro that would resize the table to fit the content. Right now I have this code and I keep getting the error that my range is invalid. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
Workbooks("A-50 -Suivi des risques V.0.xlsm").Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

Dim SelRange As Range
Set SelRange = Selection

Workbooks("A-50 -Suivi des risques V.0.xlsm").Sheets("Feuil1").ListObjects("Tableau12").Resize Range(SelRange)
```

Comment: `.Resize selRange`. `selRange` is already a `Range` and should not be enclosed in a  `Range` call.

Comment: Don't use `Select` that is a very bad practice. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) if you want your code to be reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```vb
With Workbooks("A-50 -Suivi des risques V.0.xlsm").Sheets("Feuil1")
    .ListObjects("Tableau12").Resize .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
End With
```